# javascript function didn't refresh my php code

Tags: javascript, php

I want to refresh my div with PHP code in div tag but it's don't work.
console said:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).load is not a function

at doRefresh

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
 
</head>
<body>
<div id="actu">
    <?php include 'process.php'; ?>
</div>
 
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
        function doRefresh(){
           $("#actu").load("process.php");
        }
        $(function() {
            setInterval(doRefresh, 2000);
        });
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

### EDIT

OP has updated code based on answer and comments.

Comment: You fundamentally mistunderstand how this works. PHP code is executed before the page is sent to the browser. JavaScript code is only executed on the browser. You cannot communicate between JavaScript code and PHP code directly. You need to use something like AJAX to send requests back and forth.

Comment: `</script></script>` < there shouldn't 2 of those.

Comment: You're loading two different versions of jquery. That may create a conflict. Remove one of your jquery src lines. Also make sure that `process.php` is not including any other jquery libraries.

Comment: @AdamSvestka [Your edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24891729) is removing one of the scripts tags. We are *not* allowed to modify code. I declined the edit.

Comment: @SumnerEvans `load()` is an AJAX shorthand method for jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include your code in a document ready handler to ensure the script will run once the page loads:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $( document ).ready(function() {
        function doRefresh(){
           $("#actu").load("process.php");
        }

        setInterval(doRefresh, 5000);

    });
</script>
```

In addition, remove one of the jQuery library requests as this may cause problems. You also have an extra `</script>` tag which should be removed.

You do not need the second document handler, but it should not hurt anything.          I have removed iy here.

Comment: i've the same error :"Uncaught TypeError: $(...).load is not a function
    at doRefresh".   Div tag contents didn't refresh

Comment: Did you remove one of the jQuery libraries?

Comment: yes i keep "<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>" in header

Comment: Still not working. I edited my code with corrections

Comment: I've edited the code (it will not make a difference, just removed some unnecessary bits). Are you running this on a web server? I . cannot replicate your issue.